# Is this a polite way to ask questions?

Tags: american-english, british-english, politeness

I want to send questions to someone, I want to ask you if this way is polite and if there are better ways:

> - I want to ask you questions, your answers would be appreciated
> - I want to ask you questions, your efforts would be appreciated
> - would you please check these questions and answer me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

> Dear So-and-so,
>
> I'm curious about your recent statement that ***_*____** and I'd like to ask you some questions regarding this.
>
> {questions}
>
> I appreciate your help.

or

> ...your recent statement in {publication} and...

or

> You have a reputation for ***_*__**. I'd like to ask you some questions regarding ***_*__**.

Comment: what is the meaning of `regarding this` in your first sentence ?